# JSON Attribute Error str has no attribute JSON when collecting data off of web site

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, etherscan

I'm making a program to collect specific data off of a web site, and I'm using cloud scraper so I don't get blocked. I have used cloud scraper before and It works perfectly fine. Only thing now is I'm trying to get the gas guzzlers on etheruem but when I try connecting to opensea I get an error. Would anyone know of a solution or an API I can use to get gas guzzlers?

`````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = response.json()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'```

Code
import cloudscraper
import json
import re
from json import loads

# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()
response = scraper.get("https://etherscan.io/gastracker").text 
data = response.json()
b = json.loads(data)
print(b)````
`````

Comment: Remove the access to the attrubute `text` when assigning to `response` to actually get the response object, which has the method `json()`.

Comment: @RichardNeumann it works but how would i get the specific gas guzzler data?